# How to remove already added divider in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 buttons and a `Recyclerview`. On click of each button, I am updating the Recyclerview list. Now one list will have a divider and others should not. I am using the following way to add a divider to the `Recyclerview` list:

```
val divider = DividerItemDecoration(this@HomeActivity, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL)
    divider.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@HomeActivity, R.drawable.divider)!!)
binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider)
```

The problem is how can I remove the divider dynamically when I update the list?

UPDATE:

I am using the removeItemDecoration() method to clear the divider. But it's not working. Basically, I have three different `ViewType` in `Recyclerview`. Here is my code:

```
if(sectionList[0].layerType == DOUBLE_LIST || sectionList[0].layerType == SINGLE_LIST_AUTO) {
      binding.itemRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider)
    }else{
      binding.itemRecyclerView.removeItemDecoration(divider)
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `removeItemDecoration(divider);`?

Comment: I used a simple if statement to add ItemDecoration and remove it. But the removal is not working. I even debugged it and the call is coming to `removeItemDecoration`. @Abbas

Comment: Include that code in the question. Also it might not hurt put `invalidate()` call after removing item decoration.

Comment: Just to clarify, since you don't show it in your code; you're removing the same divider instance which you added?